# How to setup Laravel Homestead server to run locally without being on a network/internet?

Tags: laravel, nginx, vagrant, offline, homestead

Previously, I manually setup my own VM on VirtualBox and configured it so it would also work when I'm coding offline (no internet/not connected to a router). I did this using settings in the VirtualBox GUI and also in Apache on the VM.

Now I'm interested in learning nginx and I've decided to try and use Laravel's Homestead. The tutorials I'm looking at seem to have the assumption I will be accessing the Homestead VM across the network (even though of course it's on the same PC). What do I need to do to ensure the VM will be accessible when I'm offline (like when I'm coding on a plane or train)? I'd like to still be able to have access to the internet from the VM whenever I do get back on WiFi (ie. for apt-get, etc.).

(note: My host machine is running Windows 7 64-bit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any VM running on your development machine will be accessible when you're offline. Just make sure you setup your development machine's host file to have the VM's location set.

If you're following the [Laravel Homestead Setup](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/homestead):

In `scripts/homestead.rb`, you'll have a line that has the IP Address of the VM.

```
# in scripts/homestead.rb

# Configure A Private Network IP
config.vm.network :private_network, ip: settings["ip"] ||= "192.168.10.10"
```

Add this IP address into to your `hosts` file. This is located usually in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

```
#in hosts file
192.168.10.10  yourwebsite.dev
```

Comment: Just because you're not connected to the internet doesn't mean you have no network :) VM should work fine (after its installed and setup) offline.

Comment: By network I mean that I'm not connected to any router. But I disabled my network adapter (to be fully offline) and everything ran!

Answer (score 1):

1. Download and install fresh copies of Vagrant and Virtualbox.

https://dl.bintray.com/mitchellh/vagrant/vagrant_1.7.2.msi

http://dlc-cdn.sun.com/virtualbox/4.3.22/VirtualBox-4.3.22-98236-Win.exe

2. Also download laravel/homestead manually
   https://vagrantcloud.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/0.2.2/providers/virtualbox.box

to my downloads folder C:\Downloads\homestead-0-2-2.box

3. After Installing Virtualbox and Vagrant. Installed laravel/homestead by running the following command in git bash (you can download git bash here: http://git-scm.com/downloads).

   vagrant box add laravel/homestead  /c/downloads/homestead-0-2-2.box
4. Run this command inside C:\users\yourusername

   git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git Homestead

NB: This will create this folder: `C:\Users\yourusername\Homestead`

With some files.

5. Still in Git bash, cd into `C:\Users\yourusername\Homestead` and run this command:

   bash init.sh

NB: this will create a folder `C:\Users\yourusername\.homestead` that contains Homestead.yaml and some other files

6. Then Generate an SSH key which you will need when you want to login to your VM by running this command:

   ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "youremailaddress@youremail.com"

NB: This will ask some question simply hit enter or type yes and hit enter.
This will create your ssh key inside `C:\Users\yourusername\.ssh`

7. Then you need to configure homestead by editing for **Nginx**

   C:\Users\digitlimit\Homestead\Homestead.yaml

You can right-click Homestead.yaml file then click open then choose to open with wordpad.

My Homestead.yaml looks this after editing:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: /wamp/www
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: laravel.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/laravel/public

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
```

NB: To understand the mapping which is a process of sharing a folder between the host and the VM:

My laravel project is located at `C:\wamp\www\laravel`

This directory `/home/vagrant/Code` will be inside the VM after installation.

So what am telling VM is, whenever you see /home/vagrant/Code reference this folder  `C:\wamp\www\laravel`

Also in this:

```
sites:
        - map: laravel.dev
          to: /home/vagrant/Code/laravel/public
```

What we are  saying here is when i go to my browser and type http://laravel.dev display the content of `/home/vagrant/Code/laravel/public` which is actually pointing to `C:\www\wamp\laravel\public`

After editing Homestead.yaml file save your chnages

NB: Before we can use http://laravel.dev in the host web browser to view our laravel project, we need to add this the following to the hosts file located in

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

Add this ip address under the list of other ip address listed if any:

```
192.168.10.10 laravel.dev
```

8. Finally, go back to your Git bash, ensure you are in 
   `/c/Users/yourusername/homestead` and type:

   vagrant up

Wait for vagrant to complete its processes. Click yes when you see any dialog box asking for permission to create network adapter on your system

Comment: Dude, you the best